# NPE on Putting Key/Value in HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a simple Hashmap `public HashMap<String,String> StoreDet;`. Now, whenever I try to put some value as:

```
String val = (eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0)
        .getTextContent()
        + "^"
        + eElement.getElementsByTagName("state").item(0)
                .getTextContent() + "^" + eElement
        .getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getTextContent());
val = val.trim().toString();
System.out.println(val);

String key = eElement.getAttribute("id").trim().toString();
System.out.println(key);
//System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("id")+" "+ (eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent()+"^"+eElement.getElementsByTagName("state").item(0).getTextContent()+"^"+eElement.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getTextContent()));
//(eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent()+"^"+eElement.getElementsByTagName("state").item(0).getTextContent()+"^"+eElement.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getTextContent())

StoreDet.put(key, val); // I get an NPE at this line
```

I get an NPE at the line indicated. The SOP's show correct values for both key and value, yet the exception is still occurring. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're getting it at that line, StoreDet must be null.  Do you ever create it via new?

Comment: *big green grin* :D 03:00 coding taking a toll over mah head :p Srry can't accept this as answer before 12mins :|